# Remove push notifications api?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Is it possible to check application for using push notifications api? I removed push notifications from the app, but my app rejected with the following warning:

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include
>   API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the
>   app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
>   make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
>   Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
>   Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push
>   Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does
>   not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required.
>   You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.
>   If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the
>   developer for information on removing the API.

So As I understand I should:

> If your app does
>   not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required.
>   You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.

Is is possible to check for the api?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue but with a Cordova App on iOS, ignoring the warning could cause a future app reject with no advice so I suggest to solve it. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168713/cordova-app-that-doesnt-use-push-notifications-missing-push-notification-enti) helped me.

I hope this helps you too.