# Cordova app that doesn't use push notifications: "Missing push notification entitlement"

Tags: android, ios, cordova

We've got a Cordova based iOS app that does not use push notifications.  As of Cordova 3.5.0, each submission we have made to the app store results in an email informing us that our app includes API used to register with Apple's Push Notification Service, but doesn't have push notification entitlement.

The app has been accepted each time, as we don't actually use push notifications for anything.  However, I would like to avoid triggering this warning in case Apple decides to change their policy as to whether these API references are acceptable.

We did not experience the issue with prior versions of Cordova, and have done no work in Objective-C ourselves.  Is this a known issue with Cordova 3.5?  Searching has yielded some folks with similar problems but I've only found solutions for people wanting to add push entitlements, (rather than figure out where the Push API is being referenced and remove it). I took a look at the Cordova issues ML, but didn't find anything there.  Any other leads that folks are aware of would be appreciated!

Plugins used:
org.apache.cordova.console
org.apache.cordova.device
org.apache.cordova.file
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
org.apache.cordova.media
org.apache.cordova.network-information
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen

Relevant email snippet, specific info replaced with [ ]:

> From: iTunes Store 
>   Date: Wed, Sep 17, 2014 at 3:49 PM
>   Subject: iTunes Connect: Your app "[appName]" (Apple ID: [id]) has one or more issues
>   To: [developer]
>
> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "[app]". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the API.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this issue?

Comment: i also get the same warning, although i dont use push notifications anywhere.

Comment: Update: sorry for the slow response.  We have not found a simple solution, as the code referring to push registration seems to be included in the default Cordova package (still the case as of 4.0). We have not fixed the issue as it hasn't resulted in an app rejection as of yet. R21's code snippet and location do seem to be the source of the problem, so I'm going to mark that as accepted. Thanks as well to Krik for providing the API calls and documentation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Krik is right ! I've found this API calls in `/Classes/AppDelegate.m` certainly generated by Cordova 3.5.

I din't tried it for the moment, but these lines can certainly be commented in xCode to avoid Apple's warnings.

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application
   didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    // re-post ( broadcast )
    NSString* token = [[[[deviceToken description]
                         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CDVRemoteNotification object:token];
}

- (void)  application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // re-post ( broadcast )
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CDVRemoteNotificationError object:error];
}
```

Comment: Just confirming that this snippet is in our Cordova 4.0 project as well. Have also not yet had a chance to try removing it due to other build considerations etc.

Comment: Seems to be accurate to my issue and most likely the cause, but have not tested a full remove/code - submit cycle.  Marking as accepted anyhow as it seems to be the correct entry point and it's likely to be a while until I'm able to be absolutely certain.  Thanks all.

Comment: @Sterling - just wondering if you ever discovered that commenting out this single method fixed the problem (i.e., didn't create any bugs, allowed you to submit your app without receiving the warning?) Thanks in advance!

Comment: @matt: we haven't actually tried it, because the warning hasn't become an issue in terms of app acceptance and changing the Cordova code would require messing with other bits of our build process.  Sorry to not have any more info for you.

Comment: I had the same issue, removed this snippet from AppDelegate and had no warnings since. It works!

Answer (score 49):

**HOW TO DO THIS VIA THE XCODE UI (6.1):**

While commenting out the offending code in `Classes\AppDelegate.m` will get your app approved, you want to continue benefitting from future Cordova upgrades so the best way to do this is to turn on the `DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS` symbol during compilation so this bit of code gets left out.

I come from a C# background so I understand conditional compilation but I am new to XCode so I had to do a bit of research finding out how to define compilation symbols via the UI.

Turns out the magic words are 'Preprocessor Macro'. This is how the you can accomplish this graphically (note that this the way its done in XCode 6.1):

[image]

Hope this helps other people out there in same situation.

Comment: Plus one for the detailed image!

Comment: I followed the first answer, found the #ifndef, went to add my own comment, and then saw this, great answer.

Comment: The image makes it easy to just follow the steps without even needing to read :-)

Comment: A very useful answer.  Thank you Steven, this is a headache reducer.

Comment: Is this applicable only to Cordova based apps, or can I use it on any iOS app?

Answer (score 4):

Have you had the Push Plugin installed at some point? Sounds like you have the respective Code somewhere in your application package. I'd do a project-wide search for the specific API calls e.g:

- didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
- didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError

The dead code, files need to be removed.

Heres' the full documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2

Comment: same here - we have both API calls with nothing in config.xml and after a fresh "cordova platform add ios" ... apparently Cordova's  (4.0) default iOS project template contains these by default #wtf

Comment: We just discovered the issue as well.

Comment: Thanks for tracking this down. Same issue as Rocco here, we're now using Cordova 4.0, (building 3.7 for iOS), have never included push functionality or push related plugins to my knowledge(we actually rebuild the cordova project as part of our build, so the current inclusions should be it...).  It seems like the code is included as the Cordova default.

Answer (score 4):

Both [kirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2917694/krik) and [r121](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4046607/r121) are correct.

In more recent versions of Cordova, this offending code is now helpfully generated inside a wrapper of `#ifndef DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS`.   All you need do is add`-DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS` to your compiler flags.  That's set in `target/Build Settings/Custom Compiler Flags/(both C and C++ release)` for those building inside XCode.

In our build process, we have been blowing away and rebuilding the AppDelegate.m file a lot.   The hack I use is:

```
 sed -i "" -e "s/ifndef DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS/if 0/" build/cordova/platforms/ios/gThrive/Classes/AppDelegate.m
 # That uses the os/x sed to not have push notifications in the app
```

which just makes the problem go away.

Comment: I've added -DDISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS to custom compiler flags but I still receive those warnings. 
Do I need to do something else?
(I am using one of latests versions of ionic)

Comment: Sorry, i've been out of the SO bubble for a bit, but wanted to say "Thanks!" for dropping in with a closer-to-sane procedure.   We've just been living with the issue but it's good to know of a closer-to-right way.

Comment: @smotru I think you have an extra 'D' in that flag. It should be `DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS `

Answer (score 4):

As Charles Merriam points out, newer versions of cordova-ios make it easy to disable touching push notifications by setting the preprocesor flag DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS. ([See bug history](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8084).)

You will need to `cordova platform update ios`, `platform uninstall ios` and `platform install ios` to get the new in AppDelegate.m. (Maybe there's a better way than blowing away the folder?)

I found a [Cordova on_platform_add hook script](https://gist.github.com/boboldehampsink/aac789c2864e16db3a14) that will edit project.pbxproj with that flag for you when you install the iOS platform. I needed to `npm install xcode` to get the hook script to work.

Comment: I have this problem but my app is still validating when I click 'Validate' in Xcode - is it possible to have an app to be rejected over this (even though the prebuild appears and works fine in iTunes Connect)

I tried the solutions above and they didn't appear to work for me unless I was doing something wrong

Comment: Xcode's "validate" never warned me about the flag. It was only after submitting the app to iTunesConnect that I would receive the warning email.