# Ionic - Missing Push Notification Entitlement

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, app-store-connect

I have two Ionic apps. I have one that I submitted a while back just fine. Now I keep getting this error when I submit a build on the other app.

```
Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API
used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app 
signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" 
entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make 
sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning 
Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution 
provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. 
See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push Notification
Programming Guide for more information. If your app does not use the 
Apple Push Notification service, no action is required. You may remove 
the API from future submissions to stop this warning. If you use a 
third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for 
information on removing the API.
```

So I have tried many things: they can all be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168713/cordova-app-that-doesnt-use-push-notifications-missing-push-notification-enti)
I tried the top 3 responses.

1. I commented out all the Push Notifications in AppDelegate.m
2. I commented out the code and set the property in `preprocessor` for it to be disabled
3. I searched my project for all instances of push notifications
4. I took my good app copied the AppDelegate.m and pasted it in the bad app.
5. I deleted all my local provisioning profiles.

So when I made my app a little while back, it asked me if I wanted push notifications. I remember clearly saying NO.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am thinking maybe I just need to make the app with .bak and then recreate the app and copy my code over? This is definitely a last resort.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about it. I've been getting the same message for an app which I haven't yet added the Push Notification code. No third party frameworks or libraries, all my own code so I can confidently say I've not included mention of Push and getting this too. This message started appearing within the past 2-3 weeks. If anyone did have push notification ability and saw this then as the alert says they just need to re-check the provisioning profile has it, though at the end of the day it's just a message, not a warning.

Comment: Okay! I submitted my app to the app store. We will see what they say.

Comment: Cool, I've submitted (updates) with it and all was fine! Good luck with the app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no
>   action is required.

I've been receiving the same warning message when submitting Cordova/Ionic based iOS apps for a while now. No action is required, and will not affect app approval.

Comment: Thank you. This can be very confusing.

Comment: Agreed. It's not always clear what will or will not get your app rejected.

Comment: I was pretty annoyed by this and luckily found this answer, upvoted! Here's a link to the official docs on how to remove the code that causes Apple to send you an email: https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/push-notifications/